# How do I store data pertaining to a month or year in Mysql

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, storage

I receive csv files at the end of each month from my customer for each of their KPI (for example csv's for resumes received, candidates joined, candidates resigned, sales, profits, loss , etc) for that specific month.

I want to be able to query this data inorder to generate reports for any month, day or year. This report will be generated dynamically i.e the admin would specify what rows he would like to have in a report (for eg a report with applications received, applications shortlisted, candidates shortlisted after the 1st interview for the period of jan to july.) for any period of time.
What would be the best way to store the data into my database in order to generate such reports? I am using Mysql as my database.
I am not sure if I would need to flush out the old data from my tables currently. So considering that I keep all the data persistent, what would be the best suited database design for this?

Currently what I do is I have a table for each of their KPI. This table has got a date field which I am using to generate the report. But I am looking for a more optimized way.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is way too broad. Read a book about database normalization. If you really need an advice on database design, narrow it down to a few tables, list all the columns, information about the columns, and so on. But foremost, have a try first and post what you got. And read a book/tutorial/whatever about database normalization.

Comment: From one customer you receive one file per KPI? A KPI is just a number. So you receive files, each containing one single number?

Comment: In this case, I meant KPI to not be just a number but a metric of some kind that is applicable for the customer. For example applications received, company turnover, sales, losses incurred, resignations, etc

Comment: Hello @fancyPants, I may be wrong, but I am not sure how a high level of normalization would help me out here. Because the fact remains that even when my tables are normalized I am going to have records for every month of every year for several metrics that are independent to each other. I have no functional dependencies here nor do I have a highly modifiable database so integrity is fragile. I am just concerned if to have a date field in my table is the best way to go or if there could be a better way to store it to improve the read performance.

Comment: Okay, okay, from your question I had the impression that you have no idea at all about database design and just want to store some CSVs. Anyway, the point remains, that this question is totally unclear (at least for me).

Answer (score 0):

It is better to store those values (month or year related values ) in a "Date" type fields which would not need any other manipulation while building reports. The conditions or logic for the specific period of time should be handled in your front end. In this case, the usage of Date field is the optimized way.